# Redirect isn´t working, Invalid redirect arguments

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I have this code... I´m using it correctly...
I´m using nextjs 14.0.4

I search for info and in most cases, it works

```
'use client'
import { redirect } from "next/dist/server/api-utils";



export default function ProfilePage() {
    const session = useSession();
    const { status } = session;
    console.log(session);

    if (status === 'loading') {
        return false;
    }


    if (status === 'unauthenticated') {
        redirect("/")
    }
}
```

It shows me this error:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Invalid redirect arguments. Please use a single argument URL, e.g. `res.redirect('/destination')` or use a status code and URL, e.g. `res.redirect(307, '/destination')`.

Comment: `import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'` see https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect

Answer (score 0):

actually you are importing from wrong package instead use

import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

This will hopefully work!!.